# Laravel 5 View not found 000WebHost

Tags: laravel-5, hosting

Coloque mi proyecto en 000WebHost siguiendo [estas instrucciones](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-into-000webhost-site/127323?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=6b55dcd797cb7a4a17e01b829c0ee3ea91d3ee95-1597262938-0-AfRmcD149JxWwVYdp1CP5JGjv2O3Fsmt5utO1ywlYlsd4W6oC_t92oVF8iyy3YLpyoYqJ2zU2M5O1pD0V-2tfW73ACqaoZqbz48yFzLM7_4hco2iCku0CzyjJQmWivmInO6MxlMcNsTI_IwnLSgSuurT0AMYMGvIoeeAm4_7VGevu_veTY3T9Wv9YqrBw_CQc-zV4vUz1jg4dX-3w_dBEwJr9L5q0bckytGtpV9NehT0XI-FU6s9nJb9HtE1GtAp_QNdKCGIB558T2qlnkcF1DWOPG1DcInL9fwzOLgIY1lDdBMhTW2si0s9yErqRaA0s_62ijy5Q7ImSo2WGHp6AV0B0CMSuENeqi6zTf88Xenx)

Cuando trato de entrar a mi pagina de inicio me da este error:

`InvalidArgumentException thrown with message "View [inicio] not found."`

Esta es la ruta:

`Route::get('/', 'TransaccionController@inicio')->name('inicio');`

El controador:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Billete;
use App\Transaccion;
class TransaccionController extends Controller

{
    public function inicio(){
        $billetes = Billete::where('id', 1)->first();
        return view ('inicio', compact('billetes'));
    }
}
```

Antes de subir mis archivos ejecute `composer update`, `composer cache-clear` y `php artisan optimize:clear` porque en esa guía dice que hay que borrar los archivos que están en caché

Si trato de entrar a la pagina de admin si funciona, de hecho si realiza la consulta que tiene  https://alquimia-servicio.000webhostapp.com/Admin

También trate de contactar con soporte de 000WebHost pero no he recibido respuesta.

Comment: Claro, en local funciona todo sin problemas y yo subi todos los archivos tal como los tengo en en local.

Comment: Ah! Si era eso, resulta que la vista se llamaba Inicio y no inicio